# Chrome extension externally connectable for all urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a Chrome Extension, and I would need it to be externally connectable from any website.
Here is what I do:

- I want to count the number of clicks from any visited website using a content script (if you know another way of doing this feel free to tell me :-) )
- I want to be able to send this data to my extension in order to store it

Is there a way I can do this? I tried to use "externally_connectable", but it can be done only for specific pre-determined domains.

Is there an alternative to communicate with my chrome extension with a script coming from any website?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you wanting `externally_connectable`? What you have described can be done in a normal content script which adds a `click` event listener to the `window` or `document`. You have not described any actual communication between the website and your extension. You have only described your extension's content script listening to `click` DOM events.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You should also read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to store the data in my chrome extension's localStorage. You're saying that my content script can access the localStorage of my extension?

Comment: Specifically, no, your content script has access to the `localStorage` for the web page, not the `localStorage` for your extension. However, generally, you should not be using `localStorage` for storing data specific to your extension. [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is what should be used. Yes, your content script has access to your extension's `chrome.storage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Makyen, I found my answer:

1. I can use chrome.storage to store data instead of localStorage.
2. I can write the following code to communicate with my content scripts:

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(data, sender, sendResponse){
    ... code ...
})
```

content-script.js

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({text: "hello"});
}, false);
```

Thank you!